# Embedding Images in WPF User Control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I have created a WPF control which I have embedded in a windows application. I have created an ImageBrush and set its source from the code behind as

```
 imgBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/imagename.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
```

This works fine when I am running the project from visual studio but when I install the setup and then run the application I get path not found error.

Comment: Is the image set to content and copy-to? And what sort of project is your setup?

Comment: Have you checked the images directory exists at the same level as the executable, and that the actual image is in this folder?

Comment: The image is set as resource. My set project is simple windows installer set up.

Comment: @RobJohnson I have checked and the images directory does not exists at the same level as executable. How cam I embed this image as a resource??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Apparently when you embed the WPF control in a Winform application then you have to add the resource to the Winform application. I added the same image as a resource in the winform application and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the images folder to your installer project through visual studio, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/4ddxk2ye(v=vs.100).aspx

Or to embed the image in the executable, just set the build action of the image to "Embedded resource" (in the properties dialogue in visual studio solution explorer)

Comment: Instead of adding images folder to the installer I would like to embed the images to the dll file.